# UserModel showing error for status of the user

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, dart-null-safety

Can somebody help me in resolving the error. There is an error in UserModel.fromDocumentSnapshot. ITs telling userstatus has to be initialized. I have initialized it but yet the error remains. Can somebody tell me what could be the error in tis code. Looking forward to resolve this error. Please do help me

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:hogoco_meet_app/model/base_model.dart';
import 'package:hogoco_meet_app/services/firebasedb.dart';

enum UserStatus { Active, Inactive, None }

extension on String {
  UserStatus get getuserStatus {
    switch (this) {
      case 'Active':
        return UserStatus.Active;
        break;
      case 'Inactive':
        return UserStatus.Inactive;
        break;
      default:
        return UserStatus.None;
        break;
    }
  }
}

extension ExtendedUserStatus on UserStatus {
  bool get active => this == UserStatus.Active;
  bool get inactive => this == UserStatus.Inactive;
  bool get none => this == UserStatus.None;
  String get getuserStatus {
    switch (this) {
      case UserStatus.Active:
        return 'Active';
        break;
      case UserStatus.Inactive:
        return 'Inactive';
        break;
      default:
        return 'None';
        break;
    }
  }
}

class UserModel extends BaseModel {
  String? id;
  String? userProfilePhotoUrl;
  String? userFullName;
  String? userEmail;
  UserStatus userStatus;
  bool? userIsVerified;
  Timestamp? userRegDate;
  Timestamp? userLastLoginDate;
  List<UserModel>? userFriends;

  UserModel(
      {this.id,
      this.userProfilePhotoUrl,
      this.userFullName,
      this.userEmail,
      this.userStatus = UserStatus.Inactive,
      this.userIsVerified,
      this.userRegDate,
      this.userLastLoginDate,
      this.userFriends});

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '''UserModel: {userRegDate = ${this.userRegDate},id = ${this.id},userFullName = ${this.userFullName},userProfilePhotoURL = ${this.userProfilePhotoUrl},
    userEmail = ${this.userEmail},userFriends = ${this.userFriends},userIsVerified = ${this.userIsVerified},userStatus = ${this.userStatus}}''';
  }

  UserModel.fromDocumentSnapshot({DocumentSnapshot? documentSnapshot}) {
    final _userStatus = ((documentSnapshot!.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>)
            .containsKey('userStatus'))
        ? ((documentSnapshot.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>)["userStatus"]
                as String)
            .getuserStatus
        : UserStatus.None;

    id = documentSnapshot.id;
    userProfilePhotoUrl = (documentSnapshot.data()
        as Map<String, dynamic>)['userProfilePhotoUrl'];
    userFullName =
        (documentSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)["userFullName"];
    userEmail = (documentSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)["userEmail"];
    userStatus = _userStatus;
    userIsVerified =
        (documentSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)["userIsVerified"];
    userRegDate =
        (documentSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)['userRegDate'];
    userLastLoginDate =
        (documentSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)['userLastLoginDate'];
    userFriends =
        (documentSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)["userFriends"];
  }
}

class UserCrud {
  final FirebaseService<UserModel> firebaseService =
      Get.put(FirebaseService<UserModel>());

  static const String Collection = FirebaseCollections.USER;

  Stream<List<UserModel>> get getUsers {
    return firebaseService.getListStream(
      collection: Collection,
      returnVal: (query) {
        final retVal = <UserModel>[];
        query.docs.forEach((element) {
          retVal.add(UserModel.fromDocumentSnapshot(documentSnapshot: element));
        });
        return retVal;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Error

> error: Non-nullable instance field 'userStatus' must be initialized. (not_initialized_non_nullable_instance_field at [hogoco_meet_app] lib\model\user_model.dart:71)

Answer (score 0):

The `userStatus` field is the only field that is declared non-nullable, which means you have to initialize it before the constructor is executed.

`UserModel.fromDocumentSnapshot({DocumentSnapshot? documentSnapshot})` is called a [named constructor](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#named-constructors), therefore to be able to use it you need to initialize the `userStatus` first and you can do that by adding it to the [initializer list](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#initializer-list):

```
    UserModel.fromDocumentSnapshot({DocumentSnapshot? documentSnapshot}) : userStatus = UserStatus.Inactive {
    final _userStatus = ((documentSnapshot!.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>)
            .containsKey('userStatus'))
        ? ((documentSnapshot.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>)["userStatus"]
                as String)
            .getuserStatus
        : UserStatus.None;

    id = documentSnapshot.id;
    userProfilePhotoUrl = (documentSnapshot.data()
        as Map<String, dynamic>)['userProfilePhotoUrl'];
    userFullName =
        (documentSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)["userFullName"];
    userEmail = (documentSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)["userEmail"];
    userStatus = _userStatus;
    userIsVerified =
        (documentSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)["userIsVerified"];
    userRegDate =
        (documentSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)['userRegDate'];
    userLastLoginDate =
        (documentSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)['userLastLoginDate'];
    userFriends =
        (documentSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)["userFriends"];
  }
```